# Return description of ImageIcon attached to JButton

Tags: java, jbutton, imageicon

I'm trying to return the description of an `ImageIcon` attached to a `JButton` with the following line:

```
tile_map[dir].getIcon().getDescription().equals("Cross")
```

This doesn't seem to work? How would I go about doing this? I tried checking the `JButton` and `ImageIcon` Javadocs but couldn't see any different methods. `tile_map` is an array of `JButton`.

Comment: Minor formatting changes.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? Where is the code that attaches icons to the buttons? If I had to guess, this should fail to compile unless you cast the result of `getIcon()`.